# Orientation of spins magnetic moments in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In a population of hydrogen nuclei, the associated magnetic moments align with an external magnetic field. Each hydrogen nucleus can be in one of two states: a high energy state (antiparallel) and a low energy state (parallel).
What bothers me is the orientation of the magnetic moment vectors. 
I would assume that the north poles (tips of magnetic moment vectors) tend to move towards the south pole of the external magnetic field. But the opposite, i.e., parallel orientation, is of lower energy (see the picture - taken from http://mriquestions.com/magnetic-dipole-moment.html).

[[image: magnetic moment vector <span class=]$\mu$ of a nucleus in an external magnetic field B0 taken from http://mriquestions.com/magnetic-dipole-moment.html">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buz6u.gif)

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what got you confused here is the way we usually learn about the direction of magnetic field lines. The notion that they point from the north to the south pole only applies *outside* of a e.g. permanent magent. Since the lines have to be closed, they reconnect inside the magnet, but then pointing from south to north.

If you want to think about the orientation in the classical sense that opposite poles attract, think of the external field as generated by a permanent magnet just below where your dipole is. Since the field lines point north to south (we are outside the magnet), the north pole of this magnet must be pointing up, towards your dipole. Now since opposite poles attract, the dipole has the lowest energy orienting its south pole towards the permanent magnet's north, which is exactly the low energy configuration in your picture.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.

Comment: Right, the field lines are connected, so outside the magnet they go from N->S, but inside they go from S->N. The magnetic field I have in mind is induced by current through a coil. That means  the magnetic field lines inside the coil are directed S->N. If I place a nucleus inside the coil, then - as opposite poles attract each other - the magnetic moment vector should point N->S. (I assume that the magnetic moment vector corresponds to a small magnetic field pointing to its own local north pole. In the image B0 is S->N and mu is S->N, right?) What's wrong about my concept?

Comment: The concept of attraction to south and north pole only makes sense outside a magnet, where these things are clearly defined. In general, it is much more useful to say that magnetic moments align their direction (which, if you want to see it as a magnet, points from south to north) with the direction of the magnetic field lines, whose direction I described in the answer.

Comment: You can also see it as: outside the magnet (or coil) the concept in the anwer holds. there is no disruption in the magnetic field lines as you move into the coil, they just curve smoothly into it. They don't twist or curl, nor are they discontinuous. Therefore the moment will show the same behaviour inside the coil as just outside of it, i.e. will not flip around once moved into it.

Comment: So does that mean, that in the image, the arrow representing B0 goes from N->S (as between opposite poles of permanent magnet) while the arrow representing the magnetic moment vector points S->N?

Comment: That depends on whether we are inside or outside the magnet (coil). The field lines don't abruptly change direction. So if we start in the center of a magnet and follow the lines in the direction they are pointing, they are pointing towards what we call the north end of the magnet. At some point we exit the magnet, the field lines are still pointing in the same direction, but what we call north pole is now suddenly behind us. So what points where is always dependent on your reference position.

Comment: If you really insist on calling one end of a coil south and one north, then inside the coil the lines also point south to north, but outside north to south.